# Passing event + arguments in an event handler callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I can successfully pass an argument from an event handler with the code below.

But I wonder, how would I as well pass the `event` to the function `handleDown`?

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    handleDown(argumentOne) {
    }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child 
            handleDown={this.handleDown.bind(this)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <span
            onMouseDown={this.props.handleDown.bind(this, 'argumentOne')}
        >
        Click here
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Btw, `super(props)` is unnecessary unless you need access to `props` inside of the constructor. Just in case you don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how would I as well pass the event to the function handleDown?

*You* don't, the event mechanism does, but given the code in the question, `handleDown` will receive the event as the first argument after the ones you've provided.

So here:

```
<Child 
    handleDown={this.handleDown.bind(this)}
/>
```

it would be the first argument to `handleDown`, and here:

```
<span
    onMouseDown={this.props.handleDown.bind(this, 'argumentOne')}
>
```

it would be the second argument to `handleDown`.

I'd probably modify the first `bind` call to pass `null` or something so that you consistently get it as the second argument. But unless React does something special, it will always be the *last* argument, so you could work from that.